# Deciding between NIntex Forms/Workflow or PowerApps/Flow

Tags: nintex, powerapp

Hi we started to use our sharepoint online and thinking of using Flow and PowerApps to create apps or just buy another license of Nintex the problem is that it cost a lot.

Do you have any recommendations when to use PowerApps/Flow and its benefits vs Nintex? Or we'll just continue to use our on prem to create custom apps using Nintex instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nintex is extremely expensive... They can be since there are few alternatives. I used flow for some workflows and it seemed to share a burden of many other apps of MS: Good idea but not really finished for productive application. There is nearly no depth to flow-workflows for more complex operations. On the other hand, there might be integration for other services your org is using.

PowerApps also seems to be a very interesting Application, since you can create apps for other platforms that can use your SP lists as a basis for data. A form as a native app for many devices. Last time I used it it was still extremely slow and unstable. Desktop and Browser Versions. And you don't have advanced configuration options if you just need a little bit of extra logic.

Depending on your needs, I would still recommend the classic CSS/Javascript approach and design your own forms or spend the money on Nintex.

I would suggest you just try Flow/PowerApps yourself. They are both relatively simple applications. In my opinion, they still don't even have the feature set of classic SP-Workflows(2010/2013), not even speaking of Nintex. But they might work for you in combination to save some money.

Answer (score 2):

Would totally agree with this comment as we are using Nintex but just got stung by the increase in subscription costs, so were considering powerapps/flow as a replacement. But MS seem to be investing in both heavily, so I would revisit that in 6 months time as both products have matured a lot in the last 6-9 months.

Comment: Any updates on you about this? have you already switched to powerapps/flow?